# how to wait till certain values retrievd then continue calculations

Tags: javascript, node.js

in the below code, I am trying to read specific value called 'mapped' from ['/proc/meminfo'] and a specific value called 'nr_mapped' from 
['/proc/vmstat']. then I am trying to divid (mapped / nrMapped) as shown in the code.

the problem i have is, when i run the code, this line is  executed first

```
'   console.log('pageSize: ' + (Number(mapped) / Number(nrMapped))); '
```

and it results NaN

what should be done so that the previously stated  log statement to be executed after procMeminfo and procVmstat are executed

**results**

```
let mapped;
let nrMapped;
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
var process = require('process');

const procMeminfo = spawn('cat', ['/proc/meminfo']);
const procVmstat = spawn('cat', ['/proc/vmstat']);

procVmstat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
//nr_mapped value
console.log('procVmstat:stdout: ' + 'processId: ' + process.pid + '-->' + data.toString().split('\n')[33]);
nrMapped = data.toString().split('\n')[33].replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
console.log(nrMapped);
});

procMeminfo.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
console.log('procMeminfo:stdout: ' + 'processId: ' + process.pid + '-->' + data.toString().split('\n')[19]);
mapped = data.toString().split('\n')[19].replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
console.log(mapped);
});

console.log('pageSize: ' + (Number(mapped) / Number(nrMapped)));
```

**output**:

```
pageSize: NaN

procMeminfo:stdout: processId: 12776-->Mapped:           321676 kB
321676
procVmstat:stdout: processId: 12776-->nr_mapped 80419
80419
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of Promises for waiting on async functions .

**Example**

```
let promises = [ ];

promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  procVmstat.stdout.on('data', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(data);
    // repeat the same for the other method
}

promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  procMeminfo.stdout.on('data', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(data);

}

Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
  console.log(data)// get the data here and manipulate the same
}, err => {
  callback(err);
});
```

Comment: would you please explain to me what does the null Parameter in callback(null, data); means??!!

Comment: @LetsamrIt actually it was my personal code which required me to pass null to the front end updated it. hope it helps